# yum downgrade does not remove new package

Tags: upgrade, rpm, yum, downgrade

**Release 1** contains the following packages

```
Package A-1.0
Package B-1.0
```

**Release 2** contains the following packages

```
Package A-2.0
Package B-2.0
Package C-2.0
```

In **Release 2**, `Package B-1.0` was split into two packages - `package B-2.0` and `package C-2.0`.

Now when **Release 2** is installed, how do I downgrade to **Release 1**?

`yum downgrade A B` tries to install `package B-1.0` which has file conflicts with `package C-2.0`.

`yum downgrade A B C` does not work because there is no older version for `Package C`.

Is there a single command through which it erases the new package (`package C-2.0`) and downgrades packages A and B?

Comment: you say B-1.0 has file conflics with C-2.0. Doesn't yum propose you a solution to uninstall C-2.0 then?

Comment: from some yum downgrade documentation: "Downgrades are tricky but in yum versions 3.2.27 and above it can do _some_ downgrades. They are not perfect and should be used with care" --> if you want to do this often, maybe look for other options than yum downgrade

Comment: @ChrisMaes, Uninstalling C alone would mess it up due to inter-dependencies (in my case). So I need a single step that would uninstall C as well as downgrade A and B

Answer (score 3):

If you upgraded several packages and then you want to downgrade just those two, then it cannot be done. Not using just yum (unless you use --nodeps and temporary break deps). There are high level tools like RH Satellite, which can do that.

If you upgrade just those in separate transaction then you can run:

```
   yum history list
   yum history undo <ID>
```

or

```
   yum history undo last
```

And it will rollback that transaction. I.e. in your case downgrade those packages.
See man page of yum for details about history command.

Comment: That really does the job, but we can't document this to our customers since it's more like a workaround. Yes, we're supporting downgrade!! And the customer can choose to downgrade months later also.

Answer (score 2):

It might be too late as you have already released packages A-2.0 and B-2.0, but what you should have done (and can still do if you can delete your A-2.0 and B-2.0 packages):

In spec file of A-2.0 and B-2.0 add: `Requires: C`

This has multiple advantages you search (and more):

- when updating A and/or B; C will be automatically installed.
- when uninstalling C A and B will be downgraded.

However:

- when downgrading A and B; C will not be uninstalled.

There is an **alternative** which I use for my projects: I use a **meta-package**:

- meta-package-1.0: Requires A-1.0, B-1.0, Conflicts C
- meta-package-2.0: Requires A-2.0, B-2.0, C-2.0

(and I use a branch with an unstable meta-package preparing next release: meta-package: Requires A, B)

Comment: Really good approach. Only reason we can't do this is because `Release 1` is already released and can't be modified now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use yum shell to write multiple operations before executing them all in a single transaction.

In your case, you can use the following:

```
yum shell
yum downgrade A B
yum remove C
run
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use the repo that was referred while executing the earlier yum command.

> yum history undo <yum_history_id> --enablerepo=<yum_repo>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).